# Accessing the right resources using RESTlet in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, api, google-app-engine, restlet

I am trying to write an API for a project at my university using RESTlet and Google App Engine in Java. At the moment, I am able to run a web server, but I am having some trouble accessing anything except from the root. Whenever I go to "/road" (which should be serving RoadResource), the web server just displays the RouteResource that is served for the root.

According to Eclipse, I get a HTTP OK 200 status code which seems meaningful although it is handling the wrong file.

The five files related to the project can be found here (except from the jars):

https://gist.github.com/majjoha/cd76272b5d6e6c368951

Since I am not able to post more than two links in a post, I've assembled the links in a gist instead.

Somehow, I think it is a minor configuration I've missed but if any of you can help me out, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove:

```
 component.getDefaultHost().attach("/road", new RouterApplication());
```

from your RestletServer code?

I think that you just need to attach your Router application and that is what handles both the default route and your /road route.  Also if you change

```
router.attachDefault(RouteResource.class);
```

to

```
router.attach("/", RouteResource.class);
```

it may be easier to track down how the routing error is occurring.